# Getting "Floating point exception (core dumped)" while iterating over array elements

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, floating-point-exceptions

I'm trying to get the 10 first prime numbers but I'm having *Floating point exception (core dumped)* error when compiling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 50

int main(void){

FILE * fp;

int i,j,cnt=0;
int prim[MAX]={2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71};

fp = fopen("primeros.dat", "wb");

do{
    for (i=2; i<=100; i++){         
        for(j=0;j<=MAX;j++){
            if (i%prim[j]==0){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
}while(cnt<10);

fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I can say with certainty there are nowhere *near* 50 values in that array. Being so, your compiler is graciously zero-filling the ones you didn't specify, which is tossing your modulo `i%prim[j]` on its ear. (and yeah your termination condition is off by one anyway).

Comment: You are not getting FPE when **compiling**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the loop condition used and the values for implicitly initilized array elements. Two things to mention here

**1. Excess array elements (when initializer list supplies less elements than the array size) are initialized to 0.**

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

and..

> [...] If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>   
>   - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>   - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>   and any padding is initialized to zero bits; [...]

**2. C arrays have 0-based indexing.**

So, in the code

```
  for(j=0;j<=MAX;j++)
```

problem is twofold.

1. After the *valid* entries are used, you face divide-by-zero scenario in `i%prim[j]`. That's the cause of FPE.

   To resolve this issue, you can leave out the array size at definition time and later use `sizeof` to get the array size which you can use as looping condition.
2. In case, you have `MAX` *valid* elements, for your loop, when `j` becomes `MAX`, it's out of bound access. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

   You should change that to

   ```
    for(j=0; j< MAX; j++)
   ```

   to stay withing the limit.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(j=0;j<=MAX;j++)
```

should be

```
for(j=0;j<MAX;j++)
```

The valid access for your array is `prim[0]` to `prim[49]` so accessing `prim[50]` is array out of bound access which invokes undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

The strange program asks to discover the first 10 primes, yet already contains an array of the first 20 primes. It also causes a divide by 0 fault, because the `j` loop limit of `MAX` will cause the indexing of a `0` value in the array (but would go out of bounds anyway when `j == MAX`).

This solution starts by knowing that only `2` is a prime number. It builds the array of primes, using each to test further numbers for primality.

The output file is in binary format - I would have output to a text file, but as that is not the main issue I have only written the primes to console in this example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(void){
    int i, j, cnt = 1;
    int prim[MAX] = { 2 };

    for(i=3; i<MAX; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<cnt; j++) {
            if(i % prim[j] == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j == cnt) {
            prim[cnt++] = i;
        }
    }

    for(j=0; j<cnt; j++) {
        printf("%4d", prim[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
   2   3   5   7  11  13  17  19  23  29  31  37  41  43  47  53  59  61  67  71
  73  79  83  89  97
```

Answer (score 0):

This here:

```
for(j=0; j<=MAX; j++){
```

**you can go only at most from 0 to max-1 [0,max)**

do instead

```
for(j=0; j<MAX; j++){
```